# SHA-1 and Unicode

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, hash, sha1

Is behavior of SHA-1 algorithm defined for Unicode strings? I do realize that SHA-1 itself does not care about the content of the string, however,
it seems to me that in order to pass standard tests for SHA-1, the input string should be encoded with UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHA-1 is based on bytes; it doesn't care about the structure of the data.  If you give it a bunch of bytes that consists of Unicode strings, you'll get a result.  Keep in mind that the block size is 512 bits, so smaller amounts of data may cause security issues.

Comment: I do understand it too. But what if I try to pass a test with "abc" and I give it "abc" string encoded in UTF-16? It will never pass it. That is the reason for question to exist.

Comment: Of course that doesn't work.  SHA-1 compares data regardless of structure.  You have to compare apples to apples.

Comment: so when talking about Unicode string that you want to put into SHA-1 algorithm what will you define as apples? :)

Comment: If you compare it to the same Unicode string (encoded the same way), the hashes will match.  If you compare it to a string encoded some other way, the hashes won't match.  That's all secure hashes do, really; they show you whether data is the same or different.  Comparing Unicode to UTF-8 strings results in different hashes because they contain different data.  That's the desired result.

It doesn't matter *how* you encode, so long as you do it the same way each time you hash.

Comment: The hash of an UTF-8 encoded string containing only ASCII characters will match that of the equivalent pure ASCII char[] string (the same as with memcmp). Otherwise you have to choose between UTF-16, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UCS-4... I'd keep the strings in their default encoding unless you intend to share these hashes

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. You could have put that as an answer because it directly answers my question